# Types of console output stream

Tags: java, console, log4j, outputstream

Besides `Standard output` and `standard error`, are there other types of console output streams in Java? I am using Jenkins (may not be relevant) and I want to add a new output section to my console besides `Standard output` and `standard error`; something like `Special Values`. I am using `log4j` but I could as well use `System.out`, etc.

Comment: which kind of values? could it be logged by log4j? TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to write a separate stream to the existing console, or write to a particular file?

Comment: @Francisco Spaeth Yes it could be logged by log4j.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using your `logger`.

For instance:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MyClass {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("name"); // declare this as field
    ...
    public void someMethod() {
        logger.info("someMethod was invoked");
    }
}
```

additionally your `log4j.properties` file will look like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/path/to/logs/application.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n
```